# Auto Hide Header and Footer on Scroll on Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, header, footer

I need a help about to Hide Header on Scroll at ListView on Windows Phone 8.1

I've founded SlideView framework that hide the header but the focus of this framework is about hamburger menu and don´t have any documentation.

Have someone the same need and Know other Framework or other way to do that?

Link of SlideView Framework:
https://slideview.codeplex.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the `ScrollViewer` of the `ListView` on which you will listen for scroll behavior. When the view of the `ScrollViewer` changes you simply hide the header and footer of the `ListView`.

I have created an example class which extends `ListView` and handles the hiding of the header/footer:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    private object _header;
    private object _footer;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        var scrollViewer = FindChild<ScrollViewer>(this);
        if(scrollViewer == null) return;

        scrollViewer.ViewChanged += ScrollViewerOnViewChanged;
    }

    private void ScrollViewerOnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Header != null)
        {
            _header = Header;
            Header = null;
        }

        if (Footer != null)
        {
            _footer = Footer;
            Footer = null;
        }

        // TODO start a timer which will restore the header and footer after a specified amount of time when this event is not fired
    }

    private static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var elt = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (elt is T) return (T)elt;
            var result = FindChild<T>(elt);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, but I hope to bring you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Vukusic!

I'll store on my Gist this code!
But, in my case i'll have to create a new control. Because i'll need add animation and work with header and footers out of ListView Control.

I'm thinking extends the SlideView framework and alter the animations templates to work with footer too.

Thanks Vukusic!